# Serial Port Test Program

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a program that read certain-formatted data from comport. The data is generated from a physical device. But currently I don't have the device and I have to test my program.

Is there a program that creates a virtual comport and sends custom data to comport and lets another program to read the comport at the same time.

*I have found some programs that I can create virtual comports and send data to them. But when I try to send data to that comport by test program, the comport is opened and I can not re-open it by my program.*

Comment: Well, test failed, wasn't that the point of doing this in the first place?  No, you cannot "re-open" a port.  Open it just once.

Comment: Build or buy a physical loop back and use another method to send data to yourself.

Comment: Here is the one I use http://www.l-com.com/d-sub-slimline-serial-loopback-plug-db9-female

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I have found [Virtual Null Modem](http://www.virtual-null-modem.com/) and it is exactly what I was looking for.

I can add a pair of virtual serial ports and program creates a loopback between these two. When I send any data (by another program) to COM1 it comes from COM2. It is great.